# Why use an offset variable as a predictor instead of just converting outcome to a rate?

Tags: modeling, likelihood, count-data, poisson-regression, offset

I am reporting the results of an analysis where we tested the effect of various demographic predictors on the number of counselling sessions undertaken by participants during a clinical trial. I ran a Poisson regression with number of sessions as the outcome variable. To control for exposure I included an additional predictor, the log of the number of weeks each person was enrolled in the trial.

I have read [e.g. here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175349/in-a-poisson-model-what-is-the-difference-between-using-time-as-a-covariate-or) that including this offset variable effectively turns the count into a rate.

My questions is **rather than including the offset variable as a predictor, why not simply convert the count outcome variable *itself* into a rate?**

For example in my study I could just divide the number of counselling sessions by the number of weeks attended. Is there a good reason not to do this and instead use the offset variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principal reason is to be able to use a Poisson likelihood function. The same reason would apply with a negative binomial likelihood function, or any other count likelihood when using a generalized linear model with a log link function. Using a calculated rate directly as a response, you lose that opportunity. For details see [When to use an offset in a Poisson regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression)

For one, if the data really are generated by some Poisson process, presumably a Poisson likelihood is better, simply because it is the correct one! And, even if it is not strictly a Poisson process, a Poisson distribution (or some other count data distribution) is probably a better approximation.

Not strictly related to this (it is more related to the use of a log link function, which could also be used with a Gaussian likelihood):  Counts is an **extensive variable**, see [Goodness of fit and which model to choose linear regression or Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353)

Comment: Thank you @kjetl b halvorsen. Why is it so bad to lose the opportunity to use the Poisson likelihood function? Is it better for rates than a Gaussian? e.g. does the Poisson handle large amount of zero counts better than a Gaussian?

Comment: well, if this is really count data, a count data likelihoos is the principled thingbto do. Offsets can be used the same way wieth negative binomials, and zero inflation can be added, if needed.