# Baseline variable in regression

Tags: regression, least-squares

I am currently looking at this paper:
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41591-021-01487-3
The equation for (1) includes a variable for a baseline value. I am confused as to why they do this as I thought this may cause problems in terms of being correlated with the error term. Any explanation as to why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the baseline value $y_{i0}$ in

$$
y_{it} = \beta _0 + \beta _1\rm{High}_i + \beta _2y_{i0} + {{{\boldsymbol{X}}}}_{{{\boldsymbol{i}}}}\beta _3 + \varepsilon _{it}
$$

plays a similar role as an [offset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175349/in-a-poisson-model-what-is-the-difference-between-using-time-as-a-covariate-or) in the regression model, though it's not clear to me why they made it a feature rather than an offset. It doesn't differ much from the scenario where you would model $y_{it} - y_{i0}$ as the dependent variable.

Comment: I went on the link for the offset in the regression model but still I'm not understanding what it exactly means

Comment: @LilyTee offset modifies the dependent variable: multiplicative in Poisson regression because of log-link, additive in linear regression. But in the paper, they make it a usual independent variable. It serves as "base level" at the start. Making it a feature, not an offset, makes it more flexible because offset has a parameter fixed to 1, while otherwise it is estimated, so the base level is proportional to $y_{i0}$.