# Poisson regression on devices that fail during observation period?

Tags: regression, poisson-regression, censoring, offset

I am observing N devices over a period of time $[0,T]$ and counting the number of certain events $y_j$, for each device, during that period of time. I also have some specifications $x_j$ for each device (explanatory variables). I was thinking of conducting [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) on these data. However, I realized that some devices fail before the observation period ends.

Is it still valid to use Poisson regression?  Can I include a dummy variable that indicates whether the device failed or not?

Comment: what do you mean  events $Y_j$? is it a fail? If there is a fail then it is impossible that event $Y_j$ will happen I would not include those fails at all. For example  you should not include dead people in your survival analysis.

Comment: @DeepNorth No, $Y_j$ is not a fail. It is basically another non-fatal phenomenon.

Answer (score 3):

There are two situations here:

1. You know when each device failed, so you know the total time it was functioning. Then you have, for each device a variable $OT_i$ (observation time $i$) that you use use (after logging) as an offset in the Poisson regression.  See [Offset in Poisson regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100772/offset-in-poisson-regression)  Or, if you know the OT only approximately, that could still be a useful approximation.
2. You do not know, even approximately, when the device failed. Then the situation is more difficult, and we would need (much) more details and context for advice.