# Poisson regression - is offset term required?

Tags: poisson-regression, matching, offset

I am modeling rates of people given drug $X$ or drug $Y$, working out probability of getting drug.

The drug $X$ and drug $Y$ points have been matched on exposure time (person years) to specific drug.

In this case, is there a need to include an offset term or should it now be treated as count data?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression/11183#11183

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful. Is a given person possibly given drug X repeatedly so you have a count per person? Could each person possibly be given drug X and drug Y so you have a comparison within person?