# How to take population size into account when running a Poisson regression?

Tags: r, count-data, poisson-regression

My data takes the following form:
Outcome variable = no of suicides (count data)
Explanatory variables = Age (grouped into young, middle and old), Gender, Country, Year
I am running a Poisson regression.
I have been told that I need to take the population size of each country into account, in order to be able to compare no of suicides in different countries.
I have now included population in my dataset, and in my regression.
What do I do?
- How do I interpret the coefficient of Population, or should I ignore this?
- Do I need to do anything else?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression

Comment: This could be a duplicate as Glen has suggested.

Comment: If you can get the population size of each group (i.e. the population of young females in Belgium in 1992), then binomial regression might be more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but I here are my thoughts. Right now you are comparing the exact number of suicides among countries. I guess there are more people in China than in Liechtenstein so there will be more suicides in China. Hence, you should compare the relative number I would think. So divide your suicides by population and use that number to create a model. However, you won't we be dealing with count data anymore in that case.