# How to combine the results from two poisson regression analyses into one

Tags: r, regression

I am very new at both R and statistical analysis and thus have very limited knowledge, so please bear with me!
I have a dataset with country-year data based on event counts, but data for about half the countries begins in 1997 and for the other half of it begins around 2016. I was hoping to do two Poisson regressions that account for this difference (one for countries with more observations and one for countries with less) and then combine the results/outputs of the two analyses in order to mitigate the influence of the variance in the number of observations.

Is this at all possible to do in R? And if so, what's my best bet in terms of approaches?

Comment: Are you estimating the number of events for a given year or the total number of events for a country?

Comment: total number of events per country

Comment: so, the target variable is the total number of events up to present time?

Comment: Yes, the target variable would be total number of events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, there is no need to run the Poisson regression twice. Simply aggregate your event counts and introduce the `exposure` (`time`) variable (amount of time passed) and use it as an offset in the `glm` function:

```
glm(country_rate ~ . - time, data = your_data, offset = log(time), family = poisson)
```

From the reference page of the `glm` function:

> **offset** this can be used to specify an a priori known component to be
>   included in the linear predictor during fitting.

There is also a [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1) here on what it means. Hopefully, your count variable is balanced (meaning it assumes a range of values more or less uniformly distributed), and you won't run into any issues.

That's as much as I can tell without seeing your data.