# Why does adding an offset change the coefficients in a Poisson regression?

Tags: r, regression, poisson-regression, offset

Suppose I run Poisson regressions but every time the only difference is the offset. Why are my estimated coefficients different? The offset is just like any other predictor in a linear model, the coefficients of the other terms shouldn't change when it is uncorrelated.

For example if you run the last line a few times the $x$ coefficients will be different.

```
x      <- rnorm(100, sd = 0.1)
y      <- rpois(100, exp(5 * x))

summary(glm(y ~ x, family = 'poisson', offset = log(rpois(100, 5) + 1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are my estimated coefficients different?

They *should* be different. You're no longer modeling count data. You're modeling *rates*.

> The offset is just like any other predictor in a linear model, the coefficients of the other terms shouldn't change when it is uncorrelated.

No. The offset is *not* your typical covariate. The offset is a predictor whose coefficient is *constrained* to equal 1. If you moved the offset to the left-hand side and invoked the properties of logarithms you end up with your outcome divided by your offset. See this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression) for more information on the derivation. Note, once you *weight* by your offset/exposure (e.g., time, population size, geographic area, etc.), your coefficient on $X$ should change.

The R code below should help with the intuition. I modeled the outcome using two methods which produce similar results. The first method uses `offset(.)` inside of the `glm()` function. The second method models the rate explicitly. Note, once we divide the outcome $y$ by the exposure $e$, it alters the variance of the response. To correct for this, we weight by the offset (e.g., `weight = e`) when fitting the model. Both approaches produce identical coefficents.

```
# R Example (Poisson Exposures)

set.seed(13)

x <- rnorm(100, sd = 0.1)
y <- rpois(100, exp(5 * x))

e <- rpois(100, 5) + 1       # this is your offset/exposure
y_weighted <- y / e          # weighting by your offset/exposure

### --- Using offset(.)

mod_1 <- glm(y ~ x + offset(log(e)), family = 'poisson')

### --- Using the weighted outcome

mod_2 <- glm(y_weighted ~ x, family = 'poisson', weights = e)

round(mod_1$coefficients, 3)
(Intercept)           x 
     -1.904       5.907 
round(mod_2$coefficients, 3)
(Intercept)           x 
     -1.904       5.907
```

Again, there is no coefficient estimated on your exposure variable. You are *not* holding $e$ fixed while assessing the impact of $x$ on $y$. You are, in fact, dividing the *outcome* by  $e$ (i.e., the offset/exposure). Correlatedness between the exposure variable and other regressors shouldn't concern you in this setting. See this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468288/multicollinearity-for-offset-variable/468298#468298) for more information.

Comment: The Poisson glm throws a warning but it shouldn't concern you. For model 2, try `family = 'quasipoisson'` to rid yourself of any messages. The coefficients shouldn't change.