# Predict probability of outcome from continuous variables

Tags: probability, distributions, python, conditional-probability

We have a model which predicts the start time of an event (lets call it `predicted_start`). We also have a default start time for an event (lets call it `default_start`), but it's usually not correct and that's why we made the model to predict a more correct start time.

The model is doing great, but sometimes it's *wrong* and `predicted_start` differs greatly from the actual start (lets call it `actual_start`). Also, sometimes it's *right* and `predicted_start` can differ greatly from `default_start` and still be correct.

It would be nice to know the probability of `prediction_start` being correct and *close* to `actual_start`. It's not a random guess and there has to be a probability distribution somewhere ... right? This validation would also probably be dependant on offset from `defualt_start` and maybe previous event's offset from `defualt_start`, not sure, maybe this doesn't need to be that complicated?

Can't really wrap my head around this and would greatly appreciate any pointers.

**EDIT:** I have considered logistic regression of some sort, but was hoping someone knew a better solution.

Comment: I think you are asking for prediction intervals. If you use linear regression (eg with nonlinear inputs), you can do this analytically, otherwise bootstrap...

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote to Tim: To clear up my reasoning for not using logistic regression, a larger offset does not mean a higher probability of an incorrect prediction and visa versa. That's what makes this problem a bit too tricky for me.

Comment: offset from what? default_start .. this should be "irrelevant", based on how the model is setup: eg model might be `predicted_start = default_start if time < midnight else 3* default_start`. if you predict `actual start` then a prediction interval tells you what is the "plausible" range a new `actual_start` will be in, taking into account the amount of data you have to estimate the parameters and the typical error size. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval.

Comment: Thank you! Thought the offset had to be include in some way, but of course it doesn't. I will have a look at your suggestion, it seems to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about predicting the "corrections" for the default time? If $y$ is your time to predict, and $\tilde y$ the "default" time you know, so instead of predicting $y$, you would predict $y - \tilde{y}$ (i.e. $\tilde{y}$ would be an [offset variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression) in regression).

If this doesn't work, you can use logistic regression, as you mentioned, or use a single model for this. The model could be something like

$$
y = \pi \hat y + (1-\pi) \tilde y + \varepsilon
$$

where $\pi \in [0, 1]$. So $\pi$ would tell you about models' confidence about the prediction $\hat y$. By doing this in single model, it could just learn when to use $\tilde y$, and when not care for those values and use $\hat y$ values. This would simplify the task for predicting $\hat y$ as well.

To predict $\hat y$ and $\pi$ you could modify the model to

$$
(\mu_1, \mu_2) = f(\mathbf{X})
\\
\hat y = \mu_1, \qquad
\pi = \sigma(\mu_2)
$$

where $f$ is some model, and $\sigma$ is sigmoid function.

The simplest case for $f$ could be linear regression model with $k-1$ features and intercept in $\mathbf{X}$

$$
\overbrace{\boldsymbol{\mu}}^{(n \times 2)} =
\overbrace{\mathbf{X}}^{(n \times k)} 
\overbrace{\boldsymbol {\beta}}^{(k \times 2)}
$$

But if you want to consider changes over time, you could use something like

$$
(\mu_1, \mu_2) = \mathsf{LSTM}(\mathbf{X})
$$

where $\mathsf{LSTM}$ is LSTM-based recurrent neural network.

If you cannot incorporate the model that makes the $\hat y$ predictions into single model, as described above, you can build higher-level model that would either choose between predictions $\hat y$ and the default values $\tilde y$, or compute weighed average of them. In the first case, you would use classifier like logistic regression, or random forest, to make the choice. Alternatively, you may build a model that would learn to weight the two outcomes by $\pi$ weights, as described above. Such model would predict the weights, and train it by minimizing loss (e.g. squared) between weighed mean of the predicted and default values, and the true values.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The "model" is really nothing more than a simple algorithm looking for human defined characteristics. Shouldn't have used the word "model". The algorithm is _usually_ pretty spot on, wouldn't your single model suggestion potentially shift the predicted start time if pi isn't strictly 1? Also, what is epsilon in this case?

Comment: @NorwegianClassic yes, it would "shift" the predictions; it'd make them weighed average between "default" and "predicted" values. What would be the error term depends on the details of the model definition you choose, since I defined it in very broad terms.

Comment: @NorwegianClassic If the "model" is just a rule-based algorithm, then using logistic regression (or other classifier) as you described is probably enough.

Comment: Thank you again @Tim. Just to clear up my reasoning for not using logistic regression, a larger offset does not mean a higher probability of an incorrect prediction and visa versa. That's what makes this problem a bit too tricky for me.

Comment: @NorwegianClassic I never said that the size of the offset has anything to do with either of the approaches, logistic regression included.

Comment: Good point... was caught up with the idea of using the offset Thanks again!