# what is `offset` in the R function irls()?

Tags: r, regression, irls

the `irls` R function carries out Iteratively Re-weighted Least Squares algorithm (Source: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/msme/versions/0.5.3/topics/irls).

One of the argument that can be passed in the `irls` function is the `offset`. According to the website above, `offset` is defined as:

"this can be used to specify an *a priori* known component
to be included in the linear predictor during fitting.
This should be 0 or a numeric vector of length equal to
the number of cases"

Which I am not so sure what it means (could be something really simple, but I am not sure).

What is the argument `offset` for in this R function?

Thank you,

Comment: Where "there" is the parameter?

Comment: the functions for calculating the posterior mode of a Bayesian logistic regression model, and for the posterior variance of a Bayesian logistic regression model

Comment: these functions calculate posterior mode and variance, in order to enable the Metropolized iid sampling.

Comment: I think the functions tries to calculate posterior mode and variance by applying the Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares

Comment: Unless you give us more details on what you are referring to, it’s not clear what you mean. Logistic regression does not have “offset” and offset in regression is constant, so is not updated https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression

Comment: Thanks for edit, it’s the offset from above link that seems to answer your question.