# Gold standard to select predictors for logistic regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, predictor

I have a data set with 50 predictors of categorical and numerical variables and 1 dichotomous outcome. I'd like to perform logistic regression, model it and k-fold cross validate it.

However, I have stumbled upon deciding which predictors to include in my model.
I have started with the initial hypothesis making, where I try to find  some reasonable physical entity. However, my model doesn't produce any good AUC (0.74).

Then I tried stepwise (backward and backward/forward) regression combining both AIC and BIC to let the computer guess which variables better for the outcome.
I still can't achieve a better AUC score of 0.75.

Therefore, I would like to enquire if there is gold standard method in such occasion to help me get a grasp of which predictors are best in order to optimize my predictive power of the model.

I use R for my modeling.

Comment: You need to read the **extensive** discussions of this topic on this site.  You started with a false premise.

Comment: @ Harrell As someone who follows this site regularly, I've y read various discussions about variable importance etc.  I think it would be useful to OP if you pointed him to your favorite.  He could then use "Related" to do more research.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection#20856       http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24752/52-variables-after-backward-variable-selection-on-logistic-regression-on-160-var      http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215154/variable-selection-for-predictive-modeling-really-needed-in-2016     http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logistic+variable+selection+model-selection+harrell

Comment: What do you mean when you say that an AUC of 0.74 isn't any good?  What are you comparing that to?

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by 'try to find some reasonable physical entity'? Did you have a scientific hypothesis about the variables?

Comment: @FrankHarrell You say the OP starts with a wrong premise.  Maybe to be clear you can  tell the OP what the false premise is.

Comment: I've never used AUC to judge whether a logistic regression model is any good.  Then again, I'm not using logistic regression models for purposes of classification.  My point: is this even a classification problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about gold standard, but have you looked at regularizarion methods such as LASSO? They are used when one is trying to fit a regression with a large number of predictors - LASSO in particular can double as a variable selection tool. The R packages gamlr and glmnet both should allow you to easily run a cross-validated LASSO with logistic regression.

Comment: Yes I would agree with RA334.I think LASSO is the gold standard. glmnet can be used to fit ridge regression. See the following references for more detailed info:

Comment: 1) Regularization and variable selection via the elastic net

Zou, Hui, and Trevor Hastie. "Regularization and variable selection via the elastic net." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology) 67.2 (2005): 301-320.

2) The Elements of Statistical Learning (Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman)
Link: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2005.00503.x/full