# What does taking the logarithm of a variable mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, logarithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When are Log scales appropriate?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27951/when-are-log-scales-appropriate)

Say you have a bar graph displaying data, for example, "Cost of Computer Orders by Population", and you are trying to analyze the data and find a distribution. The information does not indicate anything so you take the logarithm of the variable and the graph then resembles a normal distribution. What does taking the logarithm of the information indicate?

Comment: have you tried to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale#Motivation)?

Comment: This question isn't perfectly clear. Can you say more about what you're asking? What kind of answer are you looking for? Eg, do you want to know why a variable might be log-normally distributed, or the effect of the transformation, etc?

Comment: For lots of information about this topic, please use our [search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Blogarithm+%2Binterpretation).