# Test significance between groups with multiple non-normal features

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I would like to test the significance difference between two groups by multiple numerical non-normal features to determine the p-value. If we want to test this we may use [`MANOVA`](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/manova-test-in-r-multivariate-analysis-of-variance) because it could handle multiple features, but the features should be normally distributed within the groups. With `wilcoxon.test` we could test significance with non-normal features, but I am not sure how to use that with multiple features. So I was wondering if anyone knows which test could be suitable to test the significance between groups using multiple non-normal features to determine the p-value?

Comment: Significance of what?

Comment: @Dave, Sorry I mean statistical significance difference, so I would like to determine the p-value.

Comment: I think what @Dave hints at is the question of what parameter you want to compare between the groups? A MANOVA tests the mean vector, a Mann-Withney-U test tests if one distribution is stochastically greater than the other. What's your research question/goal?

Comment: @COOLSerdash, I would like to compare their means values. The problem I face is that the features I have are non-normal distributed within each group. So I am not sure which test could be used in that situation. Do you understand what I mean? Thanks

Comment: The normal/non-normal distinction is not as all or none as it sounds. If your sample size is large and non-normality is modest then ordinary ANOVA will work well enough. Also, if the non-normality is of a simple form then a transformation might make it go away. Logarithmic transformation is helpful (and usual) for many types of data, see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27951/when-are-log-scales-appropriate