# Asymmetric distribution and PCA

Tags: pca, outliers

Could someone please explain me this reviewer comment:

> asymmetric distribution could affect Principal
> Component Analysis results,  symmetry of distribution should be
> tested. Authors should also indicate if outliers were observed and
> consequently excluded because they could affect factors

My question: what does it mean asymmetry distribution could affect PCA? And also outliers, could they affect factors?

Comment: Yes, asymmetry and outliers can affect the PCA decomposition. For an example, have a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33602/603)

Comment: See also this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/38709/3277).