# Standardization

Tags: standardization, confounding

[image]

what is the advantage of presenting area-standardised rate instead of crude rate when comparing different countries?

Would the answer be that it helps to control for confounding (where area is a confounder)? Or is it that it allows different countries with different distributions to be compared?

Appreciate if someone can help, thank you.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148657/35989

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing standardisation with stratification (splitting the data in subpopulations). Here the data is stratified by area type to allow comparison.