# Taking logarithm transformation of variable for a regression

Tags: regression, data-transformation, logarithm

I have read other links on here about when to take the logarithm of a dependent (or independent) variable.  I understand that the log transformation gives a % interpretation rather than a levels interpretation, which might be more desirable because a 1 unit increase means different things depending on the initial starting point.  I also understand that if a variable is log-normally distributed like income, then taking the log makes sense.  Also, if the theory says log is appropriate, sure.

But, what about variables like population density in a region or the child-teacher ratio for each school district or the number of homicides per 1000 in the population.  I have seen professors take the log of these variables.  It is not clear to me why.  For example, isn't the homicide rate already a percentage?  The log would the the percentage change of the rate?  Why would the log of child-teacher ratio be preferred?   Suppose there are no theoretical models supporting that the relationships should be log.

Is it the case that we view a class-size of say 20 students so differently from say 25 students that a 1-student increase in class sizes means entirely different things depending on if we are 20 or 25?  The same with the homicide rate?  A homicide rate of 1 murders per 1000 means something so different from 10 per 1000 that an increase of 1 has very different meanings?

Comment: Please search our site for answers to this frequently asked question. You may use the built-in search in the upper right corner, or [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+stats.stackexchange.com+log+regression+-logistic).

Comment: Yes, I understand the mechanics behind it.  But, I am not quite sure in the three examples I posed, for example, why the log transformation would be taken.

Comment: Perhaps a better thread than the listed duplicate is [...When is it appropriate to use the log of an independent variable?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298)

Comment: Would you prefer that I post my examples to that thread?  The second thread you posted--quite thorough indeed--now gives me the sense that the log transformation would almost always be preferable to levels, given that the variable is continuous.  I didn't think that was the case, but I could be mistaken.  Is that the situation though?

Comment: I am glad you have looked around this site. It sounds like you might now be in a position to write a more specific question that differs from the others already addressed. You can do that by editing this one and then re-opening it (or flagging it for attention if you cannot re-open it yourself).

Comment: Is the new post better?  Should I start from scratched?  I am soooo confused :(

Comment: Please see my answer to your specific question in this thread: [http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/177624/73424](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/177624/73424)