# How to obtain confidence interval for lambda and the max using R Box Cox transformation?

Tags: self-study, data-transformation

I did a box cox plot on the ozone data in R. I need to determine the best transformation. Is there a way to get the exact confidence interval for lambda and the max. lambda or by just looking at the graph to estimate.(I dont know how to paste the graph).

Comment: Normally such transformations are exploratory and, even when not, they tend to be limited to discrete values (multiples of $1/2$ or $1/3$ between $-1$ and $1$, typically). In such cases, "exact" confidence intervals seem of little use.  Consider explaining *why* you are considering a transformation in the first place and what you are hoping to achieve with it: you might get some more useful answers that way.

Comment: My lambda is approx.=0.28 and a transformation on the response might improve the R-square and the significance of the predictors. Since lambda falls approx. between 0 and 0.5, a sqrt or higher transformation might work.

Comment: This is just a comment, not an answer: The three chief reasons for re-expressing the response are to make the residuals homoscedastic, to linearize its relationship with the explanatory variables, and because theory suggests such a re-expression. Although you can *always* find a $\lambda$ that improves $R^2$, that's really a side-effect, not an objective, and the effect on the predictors is--unpredictable. Thus, you should be paying attention to the regression diagnostics concerning the shape of the residuals and the goodness of fit more than anything else.

Comment: A closely related thread (focusing on logarithms, but most of which is more generally applicable to nonlinear re-expressions of the response) is at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298.

Answer (score 3):

First, some example data:

```
library(MASS)
bc <- boxcox(Volume ~ log(Height) + log(Girth), data = trees)
```

[image]

To find the $\lambda$ value with the highest log-likelihood, this command could be used:

```
bc$x[which.max(bc$y)]

[1] -0.06060606
```

Comment: thank you for your comments and the thread was helpful. I got a better understanding than my book.

Comment: @stacy see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Example for an explanation of where the horizontal line comes from.