# Logarithmic scale on a plot with negative values

Tags: data-visualization, scales, logarithm

I would like to plot two time-series on a same graph. One series takes much larger values than the other, so I thought a semilog scale might be appropriate (i.e. linear X (dates) and log Y). However, both series take on negative and positive values. Does it still make sense to use a log scale? If so, should I transform both series as follows?

```
    if observation > 0
        log_observation = log(observation)
    elseif observation < 0
        log_observation = -log(-observation)
    else
        log_observation = 0
```

Comment: Because whether and how to transform data [depends on their characteristics (more than their signs!) and on the purpose of the transformation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298), please give us more information about both so that this can be an objectively answerable question.

Comment: The time-series are the returns in dollar vs. percent terms of a trading strategy over time.

Comment: Why don't you show them as-is, using two different vertical axes to put the two series on the same graph?

Comment: So linear with two different y-axes? That is a good suggestion, I'll try it out. The only downside is that you don't have a single axis to compare both time-series on, but at least the graph will show correlation quite well.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to use a different transformation. The inverse hyerperbolic sine  [transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicSine.html) would seem to be a good first choice here.

Comment: Another choice is the cube root.

Comment: Beware that cube roots in naïve python (`**(1/3)`) don't handle negative numbers, either (although `numpy.cbrt` does).