# On log-normal distributions

Tags: distributions, modeling, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution

Since my research data seems to follow *log-normal distribution*, I was curious to learn more about the topic. In addition to very nice answers here on Cross Validated ([In linear regression, when is it appropriate to use the log of an independent variable instead of the actual values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/298/31372)), I've found two quite interesting sources. The *first* source is a general review paper on log-normal distributions and their role in life and various scientific disciplines: http://stat.ethz.ch/~stahel/lognormal/bioscience.pdf. The *second* source is a paper, which essence is expressed right in its title "Do not log-transform count data": http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00021.x/full.

Now, my **questions**:

1) Based on the first paper, which emphasizes the *multiplicative nature* of log-normal distribution, does it makes sense to argue that, if my data, after log transformation, consists of several normal distributions (*mixture model*), it can be explained by presence of *several types of interacting factors* (one based on detected log-normality, another - on detected mixture)?

2) Should I accept advice from the second paper and *abandon* potentially valuable information, as described above, and, instead, use *Poisson distribution* for *data transformation*? Especially considering that the ultimate goal of my research study is *latent variable modeling*.

Comment: There is no major contradiction between the main ideas in these papers. The lognormal is a possible distribution for positive continuous variables, and 0 could not be a possible value for such distributions. Conversely, a common starting point for counts that could be zero is a Poisson distribution. There is some territory in between these questions, but they are different questions. I think just mentioning "latent variable modeling" doesn't give enough detail to allow detailed advice. Similarly, lognormals don't themselves imply that you have a mixture of normals.

Comment: @NickCox: Thank you for the comment! Now I have a little more clarity on the subject. What information on my data and/or SEM models would be enough to expect additional feedback? As for the presence of mixture of normals, I was referring to my particular situation, and I verified it, using both visual and analytic approaches.

Comment: I guess you need new questions on either or both of those issues. But as I don't know what your extra questions are going to be, I can't well advise how to pose them.

Comment: @NickCox: Thank you. I will be posting new questions as soon as I will be able to decently formulate them.