# Interpreting log transformations in a logistic regression

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients

[This stats.stackexchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298/in-linear-regression-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-log-of-an-independent-va) contains explanation of how to interpret transformed variables in linear regression.

In particular, I found this snippet in Graham Cookson's answer (2nd answer):

> Y and X -- a one unit increase in X would lead to a
>
> increase/decrease in Y
>
> Log Y and Log X -- a 1% increase in X would lead to a
>
> % increase/decrease in Y
>
> Log Y and X -- a one unit increase in X would lead to a ∗100
>
> % increase/decrease in Y
>
> Y and Log X -- a 1% increase in X would lead to a /100
>   increase/decrease in Y

My question is, what would the equivalent interpretations be when the context is a logistic regression and not a linear regression? Since you cannot transform the dependent variable in binary classification, it's really the last one that I'm interested in: Y and Log X -- a 1% increase in X would lead to a /100 increase/decrease in Y

If 2 input variables are log transformed and one has a resulting odds ratio 2 and one of 0.5, how can these be interpreted from a model explain-ability standpoint?

Comment: And also, same question but for a quadratic predictor?