# Do i need to log transform a variable if it displays a linear relationship?

Tags: regression, logistic, data-transformation

I am writing a thesis on the relationship between gin consumption and health outcomes for my final year at university. After completing my research, I am wondering whether I should have logged some of my control variables.

It is time series panel data.

The two I am concerned about are - total expenditure on healthcare, and income.

I plotted these variables using added variable plots - which I will attach. They present linear relationships - does this mean I am ok not logging the variables?

Any advise on this matter would be extremely grateful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this time series data i.e. chronological ?

Comment: Hi - yes - its time series panel data.

Comment: You might want to look at a piece I wrote a long time ago entitled "Regression vs Box-Jenkins" https://autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf and my most highly saluted post on SE https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers .

Comment: Neither relationship looks linear to me.  The second one is highly heteroscedastic and nonlinear (look at the bottom left).  The first one has obvious curvature.  The meanings of the values on these plots are obscure, because obviously neither one reflects the logarithm of the other: you cannot take logarithms of negative values.  For a discussion of when to take logarithms of variables in regression, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298.

Comment: Does the line of best fit not represent a linear relationship? Sorry I am slightly confused as that's what I thought that meant.

Comment: This "line of best fit" obviously is a poor fit!  Although you can fit a line to any scatterplot, that doesn't mean the result is meaningful or useful.  Its existence certainly doesn't imply the relationship ought to be characterized as "linear."

Comment: Ah okay - thank you. Do you know why an added variable plot is useful in determining whether to use log or not? (I am confused - as many papers say it is useful in determining functional form - but how).

Comment: There is an excellent discussion of this topic here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298/in-linear-regression-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-log-of-an-independent-va

Comment: Hi there - I have taken the decision to log my variables but it has dramatically changed my results? Is there any reason why?