# Is it reasonable to do log transformation on both input and output variables in multioutput regression problem?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-transformation, scikit-learn

I have been working on a small machine learning project, and I decided to use regression algorithms to solve the problem, however, I have encountered some problems in the project. Let me show some information about the data first.

Sample for data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP9fq.png

Skewness of input:

`Total_mass           3.673021
 CSWire               2.989812
 CSBNR                6.708204
 CSSheet              2.561045
 LASGeneral           0.000000`

**note: except the first input feature(i.e. Total_mass) is numeric, other input features are binary.**

Skewness of all the output variables:

`RMS_E                2.900609
 RMS_ECF              3.061536
 PS_E                 4.465471
 PS_CF                4.461390
 Total_CF             2.813939`

Data shape:
`(45, 39)`

---

I choes **LOOCV** method for cross validation, and scoring used is **'neg_mean_squared_error'**

Due to the high positive skewness in those numeric input and outputs, I decided to apply log transformation.

The following are some results I got **before I apply the log transformation** with log base 0.01:

`Model to be observed:  ExtraTreeReg
One time train-test-split RMSE:  0.1309910178784277
R2score:  0.9921648674086633
LOOCV Mean: 0.24206091710968433
Standard deviation: 0.7444181240405969`

`Model to be observed:  RandForestReg
One time train-test-split RMSE:  0.4138684511440412
R2score:  0.9296646783476964
LOOCV Mean: 0.2763118063179837
Standard deviation: 0.6038208015159212`

`Model to be observed:  DecisionTreeReg
One time train-test-split RMSE:  0.10133503115117631
R2score:  0.97932598029861
LOOCV Mean: 0.17969090902445078
Standard deviation: 0.47558247881583926`

---

**After log transformation with log base 0.01 was applied** to `'Total_mass', 'RMS_E', 'RMS_ECF', 'PS_E', 'PS_CF', 'Total_CF'`

Skewness of features:

`Total_mass          -0.226483
RMS_E               -0.384771
RMS_ECF             -0.367019
PS_E                 0.200566
PS_CF                0.150737
Total_CF            -0.201469`

Model results:

`Model to be observed:  ExtraTreeReg
One time train-test-split RMSE:  0.10554400685877796
R2score:  0.9263762125663704
LOOCV Mean: 0.07271451298683669
Standard deviation: 0.09802719638616668`

`Model to be observed:  RandForestReg
One time train-test-split RMSE:  0.16691774416704228
R2score:  0.8284156287973765
LOOCV Mean: 0.13346803792820663
Standard deviation: 0.11718363334681511`

`Model to be observed:  DecisionTreeReg
One time train-test-split RMSE:  0.20610638889224905
R2score:  0.7327556879115033
LOOCV Mean: 0.12482704851937168
Standard deviation: 0.1374598872952687`

Question 1: It seems there is a huge improvement on the prediction according these 3 models, however, I'm not really sure if applying log transformation to output is allowed and whether the results are valid.

Question 2: My model has multi outputs and if I do the log transformation to all outputs, how can I interpret LOOCV Mean (for example) and its SD values that I got?

I would appreciate if any one question can be answered, thank you very much.

---

UPDATE:

I've just read this thread: [In linear regression, when is it appropriate to use the log of an independent variable instead of the actual values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298/in-linear-regression-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-log-of-an-independent-va)

It seems it is reasonable to do log transformation regardless input or output as long as the data is highly skewed.
But, I come another question, does the model look like over-fitting?

If doesn't, the next step to be done should be selecting 2-3 algorithms which have good performance, then  applying different ensemble methods to enhance those selected models, and finally tuning the hyperparameters, am I right?

---

Results of the model with untransformed variables and only 1 output feature 'Total_CF':

`Model to be observed:  ExtraTree
One time train-test-split RMSE:  0.032427326748594255
R2score:  0.9868763161745056
LOOCV Mean: 0.06429231345199997
Standard deviation: 0.16596915107904692`

`Model to be observed:  RandForest
One time train-test-split RMSE:  0.08333369356252708
R2score:  0.9133288166659663
LOOCV Mean: 0.07519662305255939
Standard deviation: 0.1517216575168036`

`Model to be observed:  DecisionTree
One time train-test-split RMSE:  0.020437017516079452
R2score:  0.9947872307851834
LOOCV Mean: 0.06608551638333332
Standard deviation: 0.13634908323180886`

Comment: I must be missing something because I don't understand the motivation behind transforming binary features. Moreover, of course the metrics related to error measurement will change as a function of the transformation. This makes direct comparisons of metrics between methods noncomparable. The predictions for one method or the other have to be backtransformed for comparability. Finally, the R-squares for the *before* models are much higher than the *after* models.

Comment: @user332577 I'm sorry that I forgot to mention the binary features are not required to be transformed. Besides, what if the RMSE and MEAN using transformed data are really close together and lower although the R2 score is lower, comparing with the model using untransformed data? Should I still go for the model with a lower R2 score? Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: How do you determine there is "a huge improvement"?  You cannot use $R^2,$ SD, or RMSE to compare any of these models--they represent entirely different things when you have transformed the response.

Comment: @whuber I thought the original and log transformed model could be directly compared using these metrics, thanks for your guidance. It seems it would be a tough job for comparing the actual performance of this two models, I'm still a newbie in statistic domain.

Comment: @whuber If you compare nested models that have the same transformation of the response variable, then are $R^2$ and $RMSE$ as valid as usual? In that case, it’s as if we got handed the data already containing that transformation and were told to model it (it seems).

Comment: @Dave No.  The reason is that both of these measure completely different things: one of them is a reduction of variance of the response and the other measures reduction of variance of the log response.

Comment: @whuber But if the models are nested with both predicting log response, then $R^2$ is measuring the proportion of explained variance of log response in both cases, isn’t it?

Comment: @whuber Well, my original project aim is to only predict "Total_CF" column as it depends on the calculation of 'RMS_E', 'RMS_ECF', 'PS_E', 'PS_CF'. I removed these 4 output features from the model and trained the model again, it seems the results are acceptable? I thought if I included those 4 features in the output feature, they would have positive correlations with the 5th output feature 'Total_CF' because I got this value based on those 4 features, so that the model could predict more accurate, I thought I was wrong. The results of that model were appended at the end of the thread.

Comment: @whuber I also want to know is there any statistical or logical way to determine if the algorithm(s) really does it job giving good performance? I made the conclusion based on RMSE and MSE since I saw a post used one-time train-test split to get RMSE and k-fold CV to get MSE. Is it reliable? Do we need to make any assumption? Especially for the extremely small datasets. You might get there by this link: https://www.kaggle.com/travelcodesleep/end-to-end-regression-pipeline-using-scikitlearn

Comment: @Dave It's unclear in what sense the models might be "nested" because they propose radically different formulations of the errors.

Comment: @whuber $log(y)=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1 +\epsilon$ is nested within $log(y)=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\epsilon$, isn’t it? And if not, why not? If I wrote $z=$ instead of $log(y)=$, then they’d be nested.

Comment: @Dave Yes, but AFAIK that's not the pair of models under discussion here.  One of them is $y=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 x + \delta$ and the other is $\log(y)=\beta_0+\beta_1\log(x) + \varepsilon \ne \log(\alpha_0+\alpha_1 x + \delta).$