Do you usually transform gdp per capita into log gdp per capita?
I'm looking into how droughts and floods impacts unemployment rate in various countries over several years (2005-2020) and would like to control the variable gdp per capita. Should I log transform gdp per capita because when I run the two-ways fixed effects regression i get this result:
Twoways effects Within Model
Call: plm(formula = unemployment_rate ~ flood_occurrence + drought_occurrence + 
gdp_percapita + population, 
   data = df_unemploymentnationalall_controlvar, 
   effect = "twoways", model = "within", 
   index = c("reference_area", "start_year"))

Unbalanced Panel: n = 46, T = 7-16, N = 711

Residuals:
        Min.     1st Qu.      Median     3rd Qu.        Max. 
 -4.8378e-02 -5.1318e-03  1.8719e-05  4.6479e-03  5.1016e-02

Coefficients:
                      Estimate  Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)  
flood_occurrence    1.2144e-03  1.2075e-03  1.0057   0.3149  
drought_occurrence  1.5059e-03  1.4907e-03  1.0102   0.3128  
gdp_percapita      -1.6202e-06  8.5248e-07 -1.9006   0.0578 .
population          1.2502e-02  5.2220e-02  0.2394   0.8109  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    0.1021
Residual Sum of Squares: 0.10122
R-Squared:      0.0085466
Adj. R-Squared: -0.089678
F-statistic: 1.39217 on 4 and 646 DF, p-value: 0.23508´

Should I also take the log of average household size and average years of schooling?

You say you're wondering if you should log-transform "because when I run the two-ways fixed effects regression i get this result". What is your concern with the result/what leads you to ask the question? (Is it that you don't have any p-values < 0.05? Or ... ?) (You ask about logging household size and years of schooling, but I don't see those elsewhere in your question ... what is their role?)

This seems like the canonical answer on the generalized version of this question. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298/in-linear-regression-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-log-of-an-independent-va
