# Practical thoughts on explanatory vs predictive modeling

Tags: estimation, modeling, predictive-models

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Practical thoughts on explanatory vs. predictive modeling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/practical-thoughts-on-explanatory-vs-predictive-modeling)

This question has been bugging me for some time, and I was going to write a blog post about it. However, I think it is better left for discussion in this forum.

Back in April, I attended a talk at the UMD Math Department Statistics group seminar series called "To Explain or To Predict?". The talk was given by [Prof. Galit Shmueli](http://galitshmueli.com/) who teaches at UMD's Smith Business School. Her talk was based on research she did for a paper titled ["Predictive vs. Explanatory Modeling in IS Research"](http://www.citi.uconn.edu/cist07/5c.pdf), and a follow up working paper titled ["To Explain or To Predict?"](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1351252).

Dr. Shmueli's argument is that the terms "predictive" and "explanatory" in a statistical modeling context have become conflated and that statistical literature lacks a thorough discussion of the differences. In the paper, she contrasts both and talks about their practical implications. I encourage you to read the papers.

The question I'd like to pose to the practitioner community is: have you ever fallen into the trap of using one when meaning to use the other? I certainly have. How do you know which one to use? How do you define a predictive exercise *versus* an explanatory/descriptive one? It would be useful if you could talk about the specific application.

Comment: See also this related question: [practical-thoughts-on-explanatory-vs-predictive-modeling](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/).