# Choosing between Latent Dirichlet Allocation and Association Rule Mining

Tags: data-mining

[Data Mining and Statistical Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1521/2192) has a general discussion on stats vs data mining. If I may, narrow down the question a bit - are there any general demarcations that allows you to decide which approach is more suited for using - LDA or ARM? (other than appreciation for the maths in the former)

Comment: Did you get an answer for this ? I am facing the same dilemma