# Translation of the term "data science" into Russian

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

What is "data science" in Russian? I'm interested in the context of a title of the job or a college course, or an academic paper.

I'm not asking it in the Russian SE because it's a professional term, and there are many Russians in this forum who will certainly know a current translation.

Comment: Wikipedia says [Наука о данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) but it sounds awful.

Comment: @amoeba this seems to be about computer science, like databases and data structures

Comment: My suggestion: "вЕдение данных" (stressed is first "е") = data knowledge/expertise/competence. To coin from it, "данныевед" (data scientist/expert) is a bit tongue-breaking to pronounce (if you've got bones in your tongue), but repeate it several times - and you've mastered it. I think it's much better than loan translation "Наука о данных".

Comment: ...Note that this is genuine russian root "вед" and is well established in professional labels, e.g. "правовед" = jurisprudent, legalist.

Comment: After a long heated discussion we have learned that data scientist is ["a statistician who lives in San Francisco"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/196591). Now, why would Russian language need a term for *that*?

Comment: @amoeba, but honestly, I didn't understand it, why S.F. will be funny?

Comment: @ttnphns there are a couple of connotations associated with SF, which makes it funny. I never heard this joke but found it funny too, although I see a ton of these guys on east coast.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard "даталогия" at work, which to my ear sounds much better than the literal translation, "Наука о данных".

However, both seem to be [in academic use](https://books.google.com/books?id=GlfpCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA124&ots=FR4MpOnWxh&dq=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F&lr&pg=PA129#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F&f=false).

Citation for Link:

Волкова, В. Н., А. Ю. Васильев, А. А. Ефремов, В. Н. Юрьев, and Н. Б. Паклин. "классификация информационных технологий." Прикладная информатика No5 (59) 2015 (2015), p. 126.

Comment: What *is* the literal translation?

Comment: @amoeba Наука о данных

Comment: Dimitriy, I appreciate very much your input as a (presumably) native speaker. Is there any citation or other substantiation you can provide for the use of this particular term? As it stands, the answer reads as somewhat anecdotal and difficult to treat as authoritative.

Comment: How would you say "data scientist"?

Comment: Great. I see that reference lists both the literal and more "natural" terms as alternative translations. (+1)

Comment: @Aksakal I have seen and heard "ученый по данным", but most people that I have interacted with just say "data scientist". I have never seen or heard "даталог", which sounds much better.

Comment: So if you were to create a training course on data science for Russians would you simply name it in English?

Comment: @Aksakal I think I interact with a very non-representative sample of Russians, so I don't have a strong opinion either way.

Comment: `даталогия` is awful. Latin+Greek blend, you know...

Answer (score 1):

"Машинное обучение" (Machine learning) and "Анализ данных" (Data analysis) are the terms used to refer to data science in russian. 
Also a term "распознавание образов" (pattern recognition) also used, but it s a bit outdated.

Term "наука о данных" is rarely used and references more to science and less to industry.
I never encountered term "даталогия" in community.

A few references:

- term "Машинное обучение" is used in [native-russian Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/vvedenie-mashinnoe-obuchenie/).
- main data mining resourse in russian is [www.machinelearning.ru](http://www.machinelearning.ru)
- you can use the main hiring russian resource [HeadHunter](http://hh.ru) and check usage of different terms if you are not sure.

Comment: I have doubts about "data analysis". This term is used ambiguously and often in a little bit different context, at least in job advertisements. Often when people are saying about "data analysis" they rather mean "business analytics" and making pivots in Excel, while "data science" is used in machine learning, geeky kind of context. This however may be not true for how is it used Russia.

Comment: "Машинное обучение" is more "scientific" term,  "Анализ данных" is more industry-oriented to solve kaggle-like problems.

Comment: OK, as I said, I'm commenting from non-Russian perspective :)