# What are the Advantages of R over Python in Statistics?

Tags: r, python, nonparametric, finance, nonlinear

So I'm a budding quant, but came from an Economics background so what I learned first was R and, of course, have fallen in love ever since. However, I recently started doing research on why Python seems to be more valued in the finance industry, and based on many stack exchange questions (which I provide for context: [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/is-r-being-replaced-by-python-at-quant-desks), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238726/how-do-r-and-python-complement-each-other-in-data-science), and a reddit thread [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/75s36d/r_or_python_for_financial_analysis/)),  determined that, *essentially*, Python has two advantages:

- more robust integration with other languages and tools (C, VBA, etc.)
- bit faster when it comes to overall statistical analysis

However, R also has its clear Pros, which seem to be

- superior visual representation of data (ggplot2)
- access to cutting edge statistical and numerical methods

What I am interested in is the ***latter***; however, I can't find too much research on what specific analysis R can do that Python can't. Would the more advanced statisticians and analysts here weigh in on this? I know Python has access to Tensorflow for deep learning and an advantage there, but are there any non-parametric analyses or non-linear models that Python won't have access to for the foreseeable future?

Comment: Note that you can use both in RStudio. Also, R has a package for using Tensorflow (or Keras) from within R. I don't think there are many things R does that python *can't* do, but rather many existing packages for highly specific algorithms that aren't available in python. For example, need L1-regularized estimation while also incorporating random effects? Check out MMS or glmmLasso. Need to explore a dataset but it consists of repeated measures? Try MFA in FactoMineR and the ggplot addition factoextra for a quick solution.

Answer (score 2):

While it was not the cutting edge, but rather a must have standard, my Python coworker and I (R DS) tried to find a function that solves a regression model using OLS. Neither in `numpy` nor in `statsmodels` could we find this. It can cause confusion when one needs to derive significance and SE for coefficients and a linear combination. It felt strange to not being able to find this tool as a statistical tool.

The `R stats` has lots of tools some of which may be lacking in Python libraries, but I am not ready to enumerate all that is missing.

Look at `glmnet` for R (**it is also available in Python per @seanv507 suggestion**): a generalized regularized regression, incorporating Lasso, Ridge, and ElsasticNet, solved by warm-up using modern gradient descent methods; published in circa 2000s to consider it a cutting edge algorithm.

Comment: glmnet is also available in python (don't know if all features)