# Statistics? Data Science?

Tags: references, terminology

Is there a generally acknowledged "fine" line between the meanings of the two terms "statistics" and "data science"? If not, why is "data science" seen nearly everywhere? Just want to learn about the opinion from the active scholars so that I may not embarrass myself when it comes to the subject(s) nor mislead people thinking of another things when they are not intended.

Comment: Here's a good place to start:  http://bfy.tw/GeYU

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195034/what-is-a-data-scientist

Comment: Thanks guys. Those are not only info but with humor too haha...!

Comment: According to [Michael Jordan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggq7HiDO0OU): "Data Science requires a thorough blending of computational thinking and inferential thinking"

Comment: statistics - science + some computer stuff + hype = data science