# Which, if any, machine learning algorithms are accepted as being a good tradeoff between explainability and prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, data-mining

Machine learning texts describing algorithms such as gradient boosting machines or neural networks often comment that these models are good at prediction, but this comes at the price of a loss of explainability or interpretability. Conversely, single decision trees and classical regression models are labelled as good at explanation, but giving a (relatively) poor prediction accuracy compared to more sophisticated models such as random forests or SVMs. Are there machine learning models commonly accepted as representing a good tradeoff between the two? Is there are any literature enumerating the characteristics of algorithms which allow them to be explainable?

EDIT: To make the notion of 'explainable' clearer, in interpreting a regression model, it is possible to make statements to the effect of 'an increase of x units of predictor i will lead to a y increase in the dependent variable'. By contrast, it is difficult to make a statement like that based on the output of a neural network. The first scenario is an example of a model being 'explainable'. This claim is made of linear regression in both Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman's Elements of Statistical Learning (2008) and Kuhn, Johson's Applied Predictive Modelling (2013), although on review the actual word used 'interpretable'.

The tradeoff is that a regression model has far stricter assumptions than a neural network. For example, to give an accurate prediction, there must be little correlation between predictor variables, and the relationships between predictor variables and the dependent variables must be linear. If the data doesn't meet these (and other requirements), the predictions will not be as accurate. In contrast, there are models such as neural networks which require fewer assumptions (e.g. they may tolerate non-linearity far better), and achieve a better prediction accuracy, at the cost of losing 'explainability' as described above.

An example is given in the Compressive Strength Case Study in Kuhn, Johnson's Applied Predictive Modelling (2013), where the models the text had earlier labelled as most explainable - CART, linear regression - achieved the worst prediction accuracy on the data. A second set of data was also discussed in the text - and again neither C&RT nor linear regression were considered 'high performers' compared to, for example, boosted trees.

Comment: Your question is very subjective and opinion-based. What do you mean by "good explainability". Why do you consider regression to be "poor" (comparing to what? in what cases?).

Comment: I have added some additional comments that hopefully reduce the subjectivity - the question is poorly phrased if it leads to the idea that I 'consider regression to be poor'.

Comment: This may be of your interest: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-two-cultures-statistics-vs-machine-learning

Comment: To offer a dissenting voice to the close voters, here's why I vote to leave open: The question of whether there are models *accepted* as good tradeoffs seems to me a point of fact on current practice. Likewise to the question of whether related literature exists. (Put another way, whether e.g. LASSO provides good tradeoff between performance and interpretability is a matter of opinion; the commonly accepted view among practitioners is, I think, a question of data.)

Comment: Yes Sean's comment captures what I intended to ask very well- to extend his example a little further, knowing that the inventors of the LASSO have claimed that it offers a good trade off would also be an answer and appears an objective fact ( they either did or didn't ).

Comment: @SeanEaster for me OLS regression offers "good" tradeoff -- what is "good", what is "accepted"? For majority of researchers from different fields the only things that have "good explainability" are: OLS regression, ANOVA, t-test and chi-squared tests.

Comment: @Tim Sure, but I think that your last sentence rather bolsters my point: It's an answerable question with the (unsatisfying?) answer that very few models are considered interpretable in practice. In any case, the community has spoken, so I relent :)

Comment: @RobertdeGraaf You may want to check [here](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/bhmk1974/26/1/26_1_29/_article) and follow the trail of citations forward and back.