# Are there good recent (i.e. year 2018) papers and discussions on the issue of "Statistics vs. Machine Learning"?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, references

I try to get an overview about the most recent discussions of how machine learning and classical statistics differ.

There is an excellent discussion on this issue here on stackexchange ( [The Two Cultures: statistics vs. machine learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-two-cultures-statistics-vs-machine-learning) ), but the original posts are about 8 years old by now.

Does anyone know of a more recent discussion (here on this forum or elsewhere)? Or are the main points in the Breiman paper still valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't go into technical details, but there are some relevant articles on my blog [fharrell.com](http://fharrell.com), and today I'll be posting a new article giving overall guidance in making the choice between statistical models and machine learning.  I'd welcome discussion about that article, either on the blog or here.

Comment: In your post, can you link directly to some articles you feel are good examples?

Comment: I have not done a good enough job surveying the literature to be able to do that at present, but I will include 2 interesting references.  We need more.

Comment: Ah, I was unclear in my comment. By "post", I was referring to this post above, and by "articles", I meant specifically _your_ blog articles.