# References for translating between ML/AI and stats disciplines

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, references

Do you know great resources (books, blogs, applications, youtube) for translating between the disciplines of statistics and machine learning/artificial intelligence? Some call it [cultures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-two-cultures-statistics-vs-machine-learning), and they seem to exist on [SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266067/difference-between-the-cross-validated-and-data-science-se-sites).

I'd like to be better able to understand when different labels are used for the same concepts.